# Jquery mobile and PhoneGap: Reload page to get next item in database

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to reload the page after the user swipe right to the next item in database (id will increment 1) but it is not functioning. It show the alert (ID+1) but the page still does not reload or changePage(same page) to get the new item.

```
$('#word').live( 'swipeleft', function( e ) {
alert( 'You swiped right!' );
if(parseInt(sessionStorage.currWord_ID) >= parseInt(sessionStorage.firstWordID) && parseInt(sessionStorage.currWord_ID) < parseInt(sessionStorage.lastWordID)){
    sessionStorage.currWord_ID = parseInt(sessionStorage.currWord_ID) + 1;
    alert("ID +1");
    $.mobile.changePage($("#word"),{transition: "pop",reloadPage: true});
}

 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

To reload / refresh your page, you may wanna try this:

```
$('#word').live( 'swipeleft', function( e ) {
    alert( 'You swiped right!' );
    if(parseInt(sessionStorage.currWord_ID) >= parseInt(sessionStorage.firstWordID) &&   parseInt(sessionStorage.currWord_ID) < parseInt(sessionStorage.lastWordID)){
        sessionStorage.currWord_ID = parseInt(sessionStorage.currWord_ID) + 1;
        alert("ID +1");
        $(location).attr('href',"index.html");
    }
});
```

Make sure that you only have one jquery mobile page (in your case "word") defined in your HTML file "index.html" :).

Comment: @AmySukumunu: Did you try **$(location).attr('href',"index.html#word");** ? :S

Comment: It get application error: connection to the server is unsuccessful(index.html)

Comment: @AmySukumunu: What about this one: **document.location = "index.html#word";** ? This should work...

Comment: Add together?
document.location = "index.html#word"; then  $(location).attr('href',"index.html#word");   ?

Comment: ok friend, check the modified solution above. This should normally work. Let me know about the results you'll get.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16462/discussion-between-amy-sukumunu-and-littm)